# Select inline to bottom

Tags: html, css

[image]

I cannot push all elements to the bottom

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <%=p.select :accounts_receivables_items_type_id, options_from_collection_for_select(AccountsReceivablesItemsType.all, :id, :title, p.object.accounts_receivables_items_type_id), {}, class: "form-control chosen-select"%>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <%=p.input_field :total_less_tax, class: "form-control input-sm mb15", placeholder: "Netto"%>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Rimuovi voce</button>

    </div>


</div>
```

GENERATED

```
<div class="form-group">



                  <label class="string optional control-label col-sm-3 control-label" for="accounts_receivable_accounts_receivables_items">Voci fattura</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">

                    <div id="invoice_products">


                    <div class="fields">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                              <select class="form-control " id="accounts_receivable_accounts_receivables_items_attributes_1397853396301_accounts_receivables_items_type_id" name="accounts_receivable[accounts_receivables_items_attributes][1397853396301][accounts_receivables_items_type_id]"><option value="126">Vendita Auto Usata</option>
<option value="127">Pubblicità</option>
<option value="128">Contratto Gestione</option>
<option value="129">Corsa esente IVA</option>
<option value="130">Corsa con IVA</option></select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                              <input class="numeric decimal required form-control" id="accounts_receivable_accounts_receivables_items_attributes_1397853396301_total_less_tax" min="0" name="accounts_receivable[accounts_receivables_items_attributes][1397853396301][total_less_tax]" placeholder="Netto" step="any" type="number" value="0.0">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                              <input id="accounts_receivable_accounts_receivables_items_attributes_1397853396301__destroy" name="accounts_receivable[accounts_receivables_items_attributes][1397853396301][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false"><a class="remove_nested_fields" data-association="accounts_receivables_items" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Rimuovi voce</button>
</a>                            </div>


                        </div> 
</div></div>
                    <a class="add_nested_fields" data-association="accounts_receivables_items" data-blueprint-id="accounts_receivables_items_fields_blueprint" data-target="#invoice_products" href="javascript:void(0)">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Aggiungi un altra voce</button>
</a>
                  </div>



              </div>
```

Comment: What about display:table-cell and vertical-align:bottom on your row class?

Comment: I tried. I get this http://cl.ly/image/46023y0K0j1Q

Answer (score 0):

In case of the floated elements you can use display: flex though would this break any bootstrap grid stuff?
http://fiddle.jshell.net/TNyUa/3/show/

```
.col-sm-9, .form-group {
  display: flex;
}
.form-group > label, .col-sm-9 > div {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap uses float left for its cols. Needs another solution.

Comment: Please post the rendered output to have a better idea.

Comment: yes, i'm using Bootstrap V3. Mayby is something related

Comment: Tried with display: flex. See updated answer. It seems to work.